# How to change Flutter DevTools default browser?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Can I change the default browser that is used for Flutter DevTools? Is it compatible with Firefox or other browser? In my case, I don't like Chrome very much, i's a little slow and heavy compared to firefox and others. I haven't found any solution so far, even changing the settings through VS Code. Thanks!

Comment: Currently only Chrome is supported for Flutter DevTools, but that's expected to change when it switches to using Flutter for Web. See https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/492.

Comment: Use Android Studio install Flutter plugin and run debug to connect to debug interface and see all necessary data. Check this screenshot: http://joxi.ru/YmEqqJiwakzzm6

Comment: So still no one has an answer to this? I have a workaround which is removing Chrome and making the browser you want to use as the default one!

Waiting for anyone to make it work without removing Chrome!

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi I presume we won't see this till Flutter Web is on the stable release channel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think that anyone has properly answers this question yet so I'll give it a go.

In my case, my computers default browser is set to Safari but Safari doesn't work well with Flutters Dev Tools at the moment. So.. how can you keep your computers default browser and specify a browser you want to use when starting dev tools?

In Android Studio open up your Preferences and in the top left there is a search bar.

Type in "Web Browsers".

You will see a list of web browsers and you can click and drag.
Place the one you want to use by default on top. For example I have chrome on the top of my list.
[image: Browser List]

Now just set this from "System default" to "First listed" and apply your changes

[image]

When you press this button to open dev tools it will now, in my case, open chrome instead of safari even though Safari is my computers default browser.
[image]

Comment: I use VS Code with the Flutter plugin. How do I change browser from there?

Comment: Since Flutter is supported by Google, Chrome debug tools works well with Flutter. But if you try that method with different browsers will not work.

Answer (score 26):

1. Use flutter run -d web-server
2. open app with browser other than Chrome

Answer (score 7):

its actually depends on code editor / ide

for vs-code

- open setting
- search `dart.devToolsBrowser`
- change to default or any other browser

Comment: Now how do I add other browser options? Currently, all I see are "chrome" and "default" (for me is Firefox). What if I want "edge"?

Comment: change the default browser of operating system

Comment: Apparently the Dart extension [only supports two options - "chrome" and "default"](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartdevtoolsbrowser).

Comment: This solved my problem. Flutter opens Firefox as expected when I run it from independent terminal, (I set Firefox as default on Windows settings), but it goes for Chrome when the terminal is attached to VS Code. This made me really mad.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers here pointed out solutions in Android Studio and starting a local server separately. But I wanted to start the whole debugging session in one command. So this is what I came up with in Linux:

I wanted to use Brave as the default browser. First run `which brave-browser`. Copy the outputted path (in my case, it was `/usr/bin/brave-browser`). Then open your bashrc or zshrc and paste the following line:

```sh
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=THE_COPIED_PATH_FROM_PREVIOUS_STEP
# for me it became, CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/brave-browser
```

Lastly restart the shell:

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
# or source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, simply running `flutter run -d chrome` would open up the debugging session in Brave instead of Chrome(though in the console output, the messages will still be referring to Chrome).