# add more debug devices in flutter

Tags: flutter, web, visual-studio-code, opera

i am using flutter for web development, and i want to run it on different browsers...

opera, chrome, firefox and etc...

so i am trying to find a way to add this to my devices list

i have opera downloaded and set my default browser but it doesn't recognize it

and by default it use `edge web`

i am using vscode as my editor

> flutter devices

output:

```
1 connected device:
Edge (web) • edge
```

is there a way to add other browsers to my devices like (chrome,  firefox or opera) ??

Comment: Have you found any solution to this yet? I am kind of facing a similar problem myself.

Comment: @ayedaemon unfortunately i didn't find any solution :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add multiple browser devices like you can Android or iOS devices. The dart extension only supports `chrome` and `default` for the web browser ([source](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartdevtoolsbrowser)).

In VS Code, open settings and search for `dart.devToolsBrowser`. Then you can change the Dev Tools Browser to default and use your default web browser for Flutter web apps.

If you want to change which browser is recognized as "chrome", you can also [update the CHROME_EXECUTABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70323974/12806961) in your terminal.

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Microsoft Edge.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Edge"

export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome“

//  restart the shell:

source ~/.zshrc
```