# Flutter use different browser

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, dart, browser, flutter-web

Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

I want to use different browser. I'm using a browser, it's opera. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can run your project with the following command `flutter run -d web-server`, wait for it to run, then you can copy the url in which your `lib\main.dart` is being served e.g `http://localhost:61262` and open it in whichever browser you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run with this command line and need to configure your web browsers preference from settings>tools.

```
flutter run -d opera --web-renderer html
```

2. Firstly, Use `flutter run -d web-server`.
   secondly, open the app with a browser other than Chrome

Otherwise, you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826656/how-to-change-flutter-devtools-default-browser/64930584).